# How do I specify a relative cell address in a conditional format in Excel?

Tags: excel, format, conditional-statements

I am conditionally formatting a row to a turn yellow if a date exists in a cell on that row. When I copy the format to other rows below, it keys on that specific cell, turning all rows yellow.

What I want is to turn row 1 yellow if cell G1 is not null. Turn row 2 yellow if G2 is not null, etc. I can manually edit the conditional format for each row, but as this condition will apply to over 1000 rows, there has to be a better way.

I would appreciate any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Remove the "$" from in front of the "1", e.g., `=$G1<>""`.

Comment: Thanks Doug, that did it. Also, thanks pnuts for the posting advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking through the same topic and indeed there is no native formula to get the address of the cell containing the formula.

I think I found the solution which should probably function as well in the formulas in conditional formatting. So to get the address of q cell containing the formula you should type:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN())
```